# Eclipse and Java: Using ProcessBuilder gives Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, client, processbuilder

I have a Master.java class which is spawning two types processes (Server.java and Client.java) like this:

To start an process from Server.java (which has a main)

```
String[] servercmd = {"java", "Server"} 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(servercmd);
pb.inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
```

To start an process from Client.java (which has a main)

```
String[] servercmd = {"java", "Client"} 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(servercmd);
pb.inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
```

Once it starts to run I get errors like this:

Error: Could not find or load main class Server
Error: Could not find or load main class Client

All three of these files Master.java Client.java Server.java are in the same folder.

Does anyone know how to fix this error or how to configure eclipse to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the best answer for you on this, but what I would do is use the debugger and step through the process. This way you can see where it is when it's failing. Also, I would check to see that your arguments are allowing you to do more than one argument at a time.
Example: Run this program and have it fail. Within Eclipse click on the 'run' tab at the top, then click 'run configurations'. Look into the 'Arguments' tab and see that you have it set so that each item can be ran at the same time.
Again, I'm not an expert with processbuilder, but it sounds like you are operating more than one item at a time.